# What is the syntax for selecting multiple layers in an Overlay?

Tags: front-end, overlay

From the documentation:

> Overlay[{Subscript[expr, 1],Subscript[expr, 2],...},{i,j,...},s]
>   allows selections to be made and controls to be clicked in
>   Subscript[expr, s].

and an example of selecting **one** layer:

```
Overlay[{Slider2D[], Graphics[{Opacity[.2], Disk[]}]}, All, 1]
```

Does anyone know what the syntax is for cases in which you want controls to be clicked in more than  one layer, or all layers?

I have tried:

```
Overlay[{Slider2D[], Graphics[{Opacity[.2], Disk[]}]}, All, All]
```

and

```
Overlay[{Slider2D[], Graphics[{Opacity[.2], Disk[]}]}, All, {1,2}]
```

without success.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned nothing in the phrasing of the documentation suggests that you should be able to use more than one layer for selections.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'd agree but sometimes in these situations that reflects inadequate documentation rather than inadequate functionality.

Comment: lol.. Mike, I just tried doing exactly this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the third argument of `Overlay` can be used to do what you want. An alternative is to change the active layer dynamically using `EventHandler` as in

```
 DynamicModule[{layer = 1}, 
 EventHandler[
  Overlay[{Slider2D[], Graphics[{Opacity[.2], Disk[]}]}, All, 
  Dynamic[layer]], {{"MouseClicked",  2} :> ((layer = layer /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}))}, 
 PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

Comment: thanks for the thoughts on a work around. I am primarily hoping that this can be done with existing options before exploring alternatives. It seems like an oversight if it cannot be done.

Comment: Correct, WRI tech support advise that you can only have one "active" layer. This is disappointing because if you design an interface with multiple layers where the embedded controls in each layer are visually separated -- despite layers being overlayed -- it would be nice to have all controls active.

Comment: @Mike, thank you for the accept.